# Differentiation operator applying on matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-operators

I need to apply a differential operator (nabla) on a matrix. Problem is, that I don't know how to calculate that. Do I treat nabla as a column vector and simply multiply vector with the matrix? Or is nabla to be handled as jacobi matrix?

Comment: I've never seen the standard *del* operator $\nabla$ applied to a matrix. What is the context of the application?

Comment: There isn't really any difference between the $\nabla$ and Jacobi-matrix (up to transposition), it only depends on where your function, defined on matrices, maps to.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by applying a differential operator to a matrix. What kind of entries does the matrix have? What do you want this differential operator to do to it?

Comment: Context is the nonlinear sigma model in quantum field theory, where I want to use a matrix function $\phi$ instead of a vector function. The matrix is a 3x3 one with simple scalar functions in it.

Comment: Treat it the same as a vector function, just with the entries in a different arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

The differential operators can be defined in a matrix of differential operators, so that, for instance, it could be applied to a matrix containing `n` vectors, one in each column.

$$
 \left[\begin{matrix}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial{z}}\\
  \end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}
  x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &        & x_n \\
  y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & \dots  & y_n \\
  z_1 & z_2 & z_3 &        & z_n \\       
  \end{matrix}\right]
$$

To see how to implement this kind of operator in the Python mudule Sympy, you can [refer to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463412/matrix-of-differential-operators-in-python-module-sympy).
To see more discussion about matrix of differential operator, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363804/handling-matrix-of-differential-operator-when-using-the-ritz-method-for-an-extre).